# Developing a P2P network project in C++ in windows, that should work in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, network-programming, cross-platform

I've got this project as part of a requirement for a graduate course. I need to develop a P2P program (having a miniature BitTorrent protocol). I've worked with network applications in .NET before, but not in C++/Java. But, I do have knowledge about sockets in C++ and how they work.

The problem I'm facing is this: The TA requires the programs to finally "work in Linux". I've hardly even used Linux before and quite naturally, I'm concerned about this.

Is there a way for me to use VS to develop programs that will work on Linux? As far as I know, I can use Qt to develop "cross platform" applications, right? Also, I think that they've also got a network package there that I can use.

Any advise? I'd be grateful for some ...

---

Comment: If you really want to use c++, and you are ok using third part libraries, check the [asio c++](http://think-async.com/). Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678367/c-sockets-library-for-cross-platform) for more library options. If you want to implement yourself, you will have some [ifdef](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/c-c-sockets-faq-and-how-to-win-linux.56901/) in your code.

Comment: I've added a link to _very_ nice blog post re cross-platform dev

Comment: Perhaps Java is a better option? I'm not sure what your experience level is with C++/Java, but it would be a little easier going to Java from C# in my opinion. Sockets are a whole lot easier in Java, also, assuming you're not using third party libraries.

Comment: I just heard back form the TA. He said that he's "not sure that the department computers even have Qt installed" for testing. He advised me to use either MinGW, Cygwin or Java. Do you think one could make a nice (relatively simple network) program with a GUI in Java, when working in Windows, targeted for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use C# on Linux using Mono? Stick to what you know - you will save loads and loads of time. Library reuse is an added bonus :)

EDIT: [This](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/10-rules-for-how-to-write-cross-platform-code/) helped me tremendously when I needed to do cross-platform C++ dev.

Comment: That's actually something I'd have loved doing. But, the TA said this: "You need to use Java or C++, because your program will be tested on department Linux machines"

I'm pretty that he's more interested in seeing C++/Java code that just wanting to get it run on Linux. I'll ask him, but as of now, I'll assume that it's not allowed. Thanks for your comment, though =)

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of network c++ libraries which can be cross-platform. Qt Network is one, and network just a small part of Qt Framework., you can try use boost::asio which is a excellent cross-platform network library too.

but when you try to use C++ which generally will compiler to native code, you have to build or cross-compile to your target machine, which mean for different OS you have to compile your code to generate that OS binaries.

another choice is use Java or Mono/.net but I think in your question you prefer use c++.

**EDIT**

your target machine does not need Qt or Boost installed. you can either static build your program or copy .so files with your program together.

MinGW and Cygwin are "actually" GCC port for Windows. Java is cross-platform. if you want to make your project done quickly, Java might be your choice, lots of sample codes can be found online.

Qt is another good choice, Qt network does have a very good example named **torrent**, which is a working bit torrent client.

all are handy, you just need time to figure it out.

Comment: I just heard back form the TA. He said that he's "not sure that the department computers even have Qt installed" for testing.

He advised me to use either MinGW, Cygwin or Java. 

Do you think one could make a nice (relatively simple network) program with a GUI in Java, when working in Windows, targeted for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, download Qt, and start with this example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-torrent-example.html

On the windows side, you can still develop in Visual Studio (on the windows side at least):

http://doc.qt.io/vs-addin/

Qt Creator is a great IDE.  It is built for working with the Qt Libraries.

The networking side is pretty straight forward.

The graphics choices are either Widgets, QML, or Widgets/GraphicsView or some other third party library.

If you ever want to take the game mobile, QML is the way to go.  Otherwise, Widgets/GraphicsView can handle most 2D games written for the desktop.

Hope that helps.